# Multiple screenshots of different domains simultaneously

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm currently writing a code that allows the user to take multiple screenshots at the same time of different webpages using multithreading.

The code:

```
import selenium
import threading
import time, datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver

domain_file = r'C:\Users\a\testfiles\testdomains.txt'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
def file_len(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
        return i + 1

current_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_')

def threadedloop(d):
    with open(domain_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:

            stripped_line = line.rstrip()
            url1 = 'http://' + stripped_line
            url2 = 'https://' + stripped_line
            imgname = current_date + 'http_' + stripped_line + '.png'
            imgSname = current_date + 'https_' + stripped_line + '.png'

            ### Screenshot function ###

            def scrshot():

                print('Taking screenshot of {}.'.format(stripped_line))

                try:
                    driver.get(url1)
                except TimeoutException:
                    print('{} timed out'.format(url1))
                    pass
                except Exception:
                    print('Unknown error at {}'.format(stripped_line))

                driver.maximize_window()
                driver.save_screenshot(imgname)
                try:
                    driver.get(url2)
                except TimeoutException:
                    print('{} timed out'.format(url2))
                    pass
                except Exception:
                    print('Unknown error at {}'.format(stripped_line))

                driver.maximize_window()
                driver.save_screenshot(imgSname)

            scrshot()

d = threading.local

start = time.time()

for i in range(file_len(domain_file)):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threadedloop, args=(d,))
    t.start()

t.join()

end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

The test file consists of 4 domains.
The problem is the webpages are not added to 1 singular thread each, but they are added to all 4 threads each, resulting in the output:

```
Taking screenshot of google.com.
Taking screenshot of google.com.
Taking screenshot of google.com.
Taking screenshot of google.com.
Taking screenshot of reddit.com.
Taking screenshot of reddit.com.
Taking screenshot of reddit.com.
Taking screenshot of reddit.com.
Taking screenshot of facebook.com.
Taking screenshot of facebook.com.
Taking screenshot of facebook.com.
Taking screenshot of facebook.com.
Taking screenshot of facebook.com.
Taking screenshot of twitter.com.
Taking screenshot of twitter.com.
Taking screenshot of twitter.com.
Taking screenshot of twitter.com.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code and realised that you have not properly divided the sub tasks.

```
def threadedloop(d):
    with open(domain_file, 'r') as f:
       for line in f:
```

These two lines in the function read every line as input to the function 'threadlocal'.
That implies, that **each time** this function is called, **every** url is read and processed.

Next, in the multithreading part

```
for i in range(file_len(domain_file)):
    t = threading.Thread(target = threadedloop, args=(d,))
    t.start()
```

Every line is **again** read and assigned to the thread, which so happens to call the function **threadedloop**.
I guess you see the problem already.

A better way is to only do the url distribution part before you create thread(*the way you have done the second place in your code*). You pass the url to the function using the args parameter which you have used to pass *threading.local*.

Comment: Could you share how you would do that? I tried what you said, but I think I'm still missing something. I changed the code, so I'm not calling threadedloop(d), but instead scrshot(d) within the loop, so the URLs are defined before the threading.
Now only the last element of the file is read 4 times, although simultaneously.